# Add data from Textbox to GridView on button click

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have 1 Dropdownlist and 3 Textboxes and I want to add data from textboxes and after a button click they will be added to GridView

```
<asp:DropdownList ID="ddlClassification" runat="server" >
<asp:ListItem></asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem>Sample 1</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem>Sample 2</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem>Sample 3</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropdownList>

<asp:TextBox ID="tbCost" runat="server" Width="100" ></asp:TextBox>
<asp:TextBox ID="tbAccumulate" runat="server" Width="100" ></asp:TextBox>
<asp:TextBox ID="tbNRV" runat="server" Width="100" ></asp:TextBox>

<asp:Button ID="btnAdd" runat="server" Text="ADD" onclick="btnAdd_Click" />
```

and this is What I have in code behind

```
public partial class SetUP : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    DataRow dr;
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dt.Columns.Add("Classification");
        dt.Columns.Add("Cost");
        dt.Columns.Add("Accumulate");
        dt.Columns.Add("NRV");
    }

    protected void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dr = dt.NewRow();
        dr["Classification"] = ddlClassification.Text;
        dr["Cost"] = tbCost.Text;
        dr["Accumulate"] = tbAccumulate.Text;
        dr["NRV"] = tbNRV.Text;
        dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        GridView1.DataSource = dt;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
```

I have done this once but now I am getting error on `GridView1.DataBind();` can someone help me in my problem

Comment: what's the error you get?

Comment: Both DataSource and DataSourceID are defined on 'GridView1'.  Remove one definition. `GridView1.DataBind();`

Comment: I feel like your gridview will get cleared out anyways because in your page load you are adding the columns on every post back. You should include if(!isPostBack){ //add columns } t

Comment: @MatthewWong now I'm getting error on `dr["Classification"] = ddlClassification.Text;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you add column do like this

```
 dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Classification", typeof(string)));
```

should help you

Comment: what about in page_load ?

Comment: its working now one more question when I enter value and clicks the button it will add the data I entered and when I add another data it removes the old one and change the new data i entered

Comment: Oh so you want to keep on adding! if so, Matthew's suggestion should fix that issue

Comment: yea just add the if (!isPostBack) logic

Comment: if (!isPostBack) in click ?

Comment: No inside Page_Load() just like you have done.. I edited my answer.